# Printing the second lowest number in a given list using a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, min

so I'm trying to use a loop to find not only one but a second value with the lowest number in a given list. I tried doing this with the for loop but instead of printing out two values, I only get one value printed twelve times. Let me demonstrate:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

# List of average monthly rainfall for each month in "months":

rainfall = [3.1, 3.1, 2.6, 1.1, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 2, 2.1]

# Calculations and printing the results:

print("1. Total rainfall for 2019 in Los Angeles, California:", sum(rainfall), "inches.")
print("2. Average monthly rainfall for 2019 in Los Anges, California:", sum(rainfall) / len(rainfall), "inches.")
print("Highest rainfall in 2019 was", max(rainfall), "in", months[rainfall.index(max(rainfall))])

for number in rainfall:
    print("The lowest rainfall in 2019 was", min(rainfall), "in", months[rainfall.index(min(rainfall))])
```

This is the result of this loop:

```
1. Total rainfall for 2019 in Los Angeles, California: 15.2 inches.
2. Average monthly rainfall for 2019 in Los Anges, California: 1.2666666666666666 inches.
Highest rainfall in 2019 was 3.1 in January
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
June
```

I also tried using the if statement within the for loop:

```
for number in rainfall:
    if rainfall < 0.2:
        "The Lowest rainfall in 2019 was", min(rainfall), "in", months[rainfall.index(min(rainfall))])
```

This is the Traceback error message:

"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

what am I doing wrong here? Please help. Also, please keep it simple, I'm a beginner in Python, and the months[rainfall.index()] code that I put in is what the professor is asking for, and also the min and max codes are also required from my professor. He also asks me to use a loop to print out the two lowest numbers in the rainfall list to match with their corresponding months, hence the months(rainfall.index()) code. Any help will be deeply appreciated, thanks.

Sincerely,
Ana Baird

Answer (score 0):

```
very_big_number = float("inf")

# Initialize desired two lowest values to something big *
lowest_rf = very_big_number 
second_lowest_rf = very_big_number 

# Initialize the corresponding indexes to some weird value **
lowest_idx = -1
second_lowest_idx = -1

idx = 0
for number in rainfall:
    # If number is lower than the lowest we have, number becomes the lowest one now 
    # and the second lowest is changed to the lowest before seeing this number
    if number < lowest_rf:
        second_lowest_rf = lowest_rf
        lowest_rf = number
        # Assign the indexes respectively
        second_lowest_idx = lowest_idx
        lowest_idx = idx

    # If the current number is not lower than the lowest but it is in between two 
    # current lowests we have, update the second lowest and leave the lowest as is
    elif number < second_lowest_rf:
        second_lowest_rf = number
        second_lowest_idx = idx

    # Increase the running index 
    idx = idx + 1

# Report the desired values
print(lowest_rf, second_lowest_rf, lowest_idx, second_lowest_idx)
```

The first if checks if the `number` is the lowest so far and "shifts" the second lowest to the current lowest and current lowest to this number. The second if is the case when the number is between the lowest and the second lowest, in which case we only shift the second lowest to that number.

*: You can use `max(rainfall) + 1` instead; the aim is to start with very big numbers (it is enough they are bigger than all the entries of the list) for lowest candidates so that all `number`s in the loop are possible candidates for lowests. (think what would happen if we started these values with -5)

**: -1 is actually not a weird index in Python so you might start with something like `None` or even an empty string; but since those are merely for initalizations and guaranteed to change (the above initalizations of lowests' ensure this, as long as list is not empty), it is okay.

Lastly, there are many rooms for improvement of this code (e.g. `enumerate` instead of running index), but should be okay for beginner level.